# PC keeps rebooting before displaying the login screen and then works fine

Tags: boot, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, cable

It is a homemade PC that is already a few years old (without problems).

**These are the parts used:**

- Mainboard: ASRock B450 Steel Legend
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- RAM: 16GB Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO
- Power: Corsair RM750
- Hard drive: Crucial P1 1TB SSD
- Graphics card: MSI Geforce RTX 2070 SUPER

**Additional info:**

- I completely changed my OS from Windows to Linux Fedora while the problem occurs, so it can't be the operating system
- Restarting the PC does not cause it to reboot multiple times, nor does turning it off and then on again

**What I have already tried:**

- Check that everything is plugged in correctly, as connections that only work when the PC is warm may be to blame
- Restarting the PC to see what happens

I really have no idea how to narrow down the problem. Any help, such as additional tests, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Test the hardware with Diagnostic Apps from each device manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately there does not seem to be any diagnostic software for my parts for my OS. I have found some software for my GPU, SSD and CPU but they only seem to be available for Windows. I have tried running them through Bottles but to no avail. Do you have any other suggestions or experiments I could do to narrow down the cause of the problem?

Comment: Given all the above, I do not know for sure.  I will look around a bit.